# How does the direction of a force applied to a pulley influence the pulley's motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, free-body-diagram, string

Suppose friction is negligible, we want to determine the force F that has to be applied to a pulley (whose radius is $R$) such that the body m has a constant acceleration a, which is given.

[image]

What I did was the following: as far as the linear acceleration is concerned, the forces acting on $m$ are the tension of the rope, $T$, and its weight, so $T-mg=ma$, a being positive. Also, considering the total momentum, we have $TR-FR=-I\alpha$, since the force F is tangent to the pulley (and here's my question: should we care about that 45 degrees angle in some way?). Combining these two equation, we can derive the value of F.

Answer (score 1):

*. . . . . should we care about that 45 degrees angle in some way?*

No. You have answered your own question by setting up the two equations without using the angle.